# Azure AD: Mixing SPA with delegated user identity scenario

Tags: oauth, single-page-application, azure-active-directory, adal.js

I intend to develop a Single-Page-Application that has a Web API as backend that will call some other Web APIs on the user's behalf. But I struggle how to do this.

I looked at this [list of Azure AD scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios) from MS but none of then seems to fit for my case.I think my scenario is a mixture of the SPA and the "Web Application to Web API" scenario from that link.

From what I understand I must accomplish that the SPA-Client retrieves an authorisation code and ID token from Azure AD Auth Endpoint first, send them to my backend. Then the backend will request the Azure AD Token endpoint for the needed access tokens.

Is this correct? But how can I do this (with adal.js)? I only find examples for the client using the implicit flow, where getting the authorisation code is skipped and you end directly with the access token. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're understanding is pretty close.  After configuring the scenario in the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com) (see [code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof) for help on configuring the scenario), you'll log in a user and request an access token the web API.  Then when the web API receives this access token, it can perform an [On-Behalf-Of request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-on-behalf-of) to Azure AD requesting access to the downstream web API. On success, Azure AD will issue the web API a new access token it can use for the downstream API.

In terms of support, the single page app will need to use ADAL.js to login the user and get access tokens.  On the web API side, Azure AD supports the [On-Behalf-Of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-on-behalf-of) through ADAL .NET and ADAL Java. One nuance is you'll probably want to protect the endpoints and validate tokens on your web API, Azure AD has built an OWIN middleware for .NET, but would require an open source equivalent for a Java web API.

[Here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof) is a great sample of the On-Behalf-Of flow in action.  It has both a single page app and a native app calling the .NET web API.

Comment: I think that's exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot, Daniel!